# In the modern world how much could one accumulate "on the quiet"?

Tags: internal-consistency

A central theme of many pieces of fiction is the bad guy who has quietly amassed resources until he is ready to strike. This is usually in the form of money, blackmail material, or a large stash of weapons, but sometimes it's whole armies (like [Fight Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight_Club_(novel))'s "project mayhem").

My question is, given our modern "surveillance society", how much could one reasonably accumulate without drawing unwanted attention?

Obviously money is easier to hoard than explosives so answers should focus on materiel rather than less tangible assets.

Comment: I would rather believe that in many countries (and definitely in most countries where one *can* accumulate great wealth) it's much easier to accumulate a large stash of explosives than a lot of money; banks have this habit of reporting large accounts to the authorities. And by the way, a "horde" is what Genghis Khan had; what a miser does is "hoard".

Comment: @AlexP If you're worried about the bank reporting on you for owning too much, the trick is to own the bank.

Comment: @AlexP Money is not however a "red-flag item" people can have millions of dollars in the bank without the ATF kicking down the door the way they will for a couple of pounds of illegal explosives.

Comment: You call our current society a "surveillance society". That point in itself is debatable and absolutely not established. It also differs greatly depending on where you live. It is fine if you want a rather simplistic view in your book (or whatever), but you have to explain what you mean by that. Who is being watched by whom? How does this hinder accumulating stuff quietly?

Comment: @Peter: If cannot own a bank without having all the other banks pay a lot of attention. And maybe I misunderstood the question, but "millions" of dollars won't buy you much striking power. And about those pounds of explosives -- I understand that there are factories in the U.S.A. manufacturing artificial fertilizers? They have thousands of tons of explosives on hand, all perfectly legal.

Comment: Don't think this question is answerable as-is. It is way too broad to begin with.

Comment: Another problem is social medias : It would be difficult to raise an army like in Fight Club, without no one posting anything on internet.

Comment: @Kepotx First rule of Army club...don't talk (tweet, post, istagram or in any way report) about Army club.

Comment: @LioElbammalf and how could the army grow that much if no one talk? If they talk about fight club IRL, you can expect that they will also talk on internet, even more under secret identities

Comment: It's all about dual use. You build something else which mainly serves a different purpose, but is able to quickly snap-turn and do *that*. For instance, if you want to be an emergency logistics and food supplier, you build Waffle House.  That is literally what they are.  If you secretly want to have an immense military cargo fleet without appearing that you do, already exists, google "Civil Reserve Air Fleet".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Given appropriate approaches, basically unlimited.

- Explosives are the product of an industry, they're used in other industries.
- Weapons are equally the products of an industry and sold on a global scale.
- Money is what you get for selling weapons.

Mostly one sells weapons to governments, explosives as part of weapons or to mining and similar industries. Given appropriate licenses, facilities etc, there's nothing stopping you building up vast quantities of all these things. There's no need to pretend to hide them either, every time a government agency comes round you try to sell them a few thousand units.

> I built these as part of an order for [mad dictator who got overthrown/under embargo] and now nobody wants them so they're stuck in stock, would you like 5000?

Easily gathered, easily stored. It's all just a matter of what sort of bad guy you want to be. Hide in plain sight, making a fortune off the arms industry while you prepare.

Mind you by the point you've managed that, it's easier to buy the government rather than messing about with revolutions.

Comment: Also branch out into mercenaries aka "security companies". As long as you don't have too many people in one location, nobody is going to ask inconvenient questions

Answer (score 1):

These days it's **practically impossible** to get away with what you're describing **"on the quiet"**. Sure, if you have the money and resources, the sky might be the limit as to what you can purchase, but you're not protected from attracting attention.

Items of a sensitive nature, be it weapons and ammunition, explosives, or drugs, are all watched, for obvious reasons. If you are dealing in them or amassing them this will eventually be noticed; increasing the quantities involved only increases the chances of that happening sooner, rather than later.

*What about buying them illegally?*

These aren't exactly things you can buy on Amazon; there are only so many people and organizations providing illegal goods and services. Depending on what you're after, odds are almost certain you're going to deal with someone who is going to put you on the radar of intelligence services.

Intelligence services are very good about tracking these types of activities on the scale that you're talking about. Knowing about it and being in a position to stop it, however, are two different matters.

*How much could you reasonably amass without drawing attention?*

Not  very much. Depending on goals though, that may be all that is required to be effective. Think recent truck attacks or fertilizer bombs. The sad fact is that it doesn't require much in the way of resources to do evil.

These actions, while deplorable, aren't exactly on the James Bond villain scale you describe though.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! This is true, but would you be able to [edit] your answer to explain *how much* someone could "reasonably accumulate without drawing unwanted attention?" Thanks

Answer (score -1):

On one hand, as we know, the sky is the limit. You can be very rich and have assets in many industries. Including weapons, ammo, technology and no one will bat an eye.

On the other hand you can own supermarket chains, order child bicycles from China and get on the naughty terrorist list because there is a tube that is exactly the same as the one used in uranium enriching process.

And you had this very rich guy. You know, Osama whatshisname. Which probably spend money on doing drugs and weaboo figurines because his organisation used freely available planes.

And I wouldn't be so sure about this whole "surveillance society". Because you know, who watch the watchmen? Not the watchmen for sure. Example: Gunrunners project.